# null column SQL with php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

**Hello How can I verify
If there any information column or not
In Table users
Here is my full script**

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); 
$selected = mysql_select_db("demo1",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select demo1"); 
//$result_name = mysql_query(" SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name` != '' ");
$result_name = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM demo1. users");
while($row_name = mysql_fetch_array($result_name)) { 
//echo "NAME=" . $row_name['name'] . "<br/>";
if ($row_name == null)
echo "NAME= no name <br/>";
else
{
echo "NAME=" . $row_name['name'] . "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

I get the result
but when there is no name i.e. name is null I want to output "NAME= no name" but I just get "Name ="
http://s23.postimg.org/ky8xcoy4b/Untitled_1.jpg
Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using `$row_name` as an `array`, so you should use `$row_name['name']` in `If condition` like,

```
if (is_null($row_name['name']) or trim($row_name['name'])=="")
    echo "NAME= no name <br/>";
```

Read [is_null()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the following code,

```
while($row_name = mysql_fetch_array($result_name))
```

If no information was found it will not enter the loop, so you don't need to check inside the loop if no information was found.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
        `if ($row_name == null)` 
      to

if ($row_name == null || $row_name == "")

Answer (score 0):

Just place your while loop inside the following if statement to check if any information is returned from your query:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result_name)>0)
{


}
```

It basically gives the number of rows of the result which should obviously be greater than zero if there is any information retreived